# Document sharing on whiteboard application using flex

Tags: apache-flex, document, sharing, whiteboard

I am creating a whiteboard application using flex. I want to add a document sharing functionality to the application i.e, the user can upload the documents which will be loaded into the whiteboard and users can annotate over the document.

I googled a lot but still not sure where to start how to start. I only got the idea that the document can be converted to series of images on the server side and can be loaded in to flex app.

Can the experts help me get started with this. I am planning to use java for the server side.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about uploading files to whiteboard itself. I think it's better to use loader and put your whiteboard on top of it.

What about software to convert documents. I'm not server side programmer, but I can share programs that we are using to convert documents:

Now we are using [Print2Flash](http://print2flash.com/) for almost all documents, but planning to give a chance for [iSpring](http://www.ispringsolutions.com/) to convert Powerpoint presentations.

Both are live projects, getting improvements often enough and can convert documents to swf files. Personally I like the way **Print2Flash** provides ability to customize resulting swf with your own patterns and gives great flexibility to interract with it. As I know, nowadays **iSpring** added AS3 API to converted files, which is huge enhancement, but it's kinda expensive.

And don't forget about [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/). It has not that good converter, but at least it is free. We've used it before, but gave preference to Print2Flash.

Hope my answer will give you a place to start.

Cheers.